# subleq confusion and understanding

Tags: esoteric-languages

Can some one explain subleq to me better? I am looking at http://esolangs.org/wiki/Subleq

There example:

```
3 4 6
7 7 7
3 4 0
```

> the first instruction, at address zero, subtracts 7 (address 3) from 7
>   (address 4). The result in address 4 is 0, so jump to 6. Starting at
>   address 6 is the instruction 3 4 0 which again subtracts 7 from now 0
>   and jumps back to 0. Here is a sequence of execution (A and B are
>   shown after subtraction)
>
> ```
> 0: 3 4 6 A=7 B=0
> 6: 3 4 0 A=7 B=-7
> 0: 3 4 6 A=7 B=-14
> 6: 3 4 0 A=7 B=-21
> 0: 3 4 6 A=7 B=-28
> ...
> ```

My first question is address 0 "3 4 6 A=7 B=0"?
Where did they get 7? Is it from the first two number? I thought it has to do with subtraction :S

Comment: `Can some one explain subleq to me better?` SO is for coding problems. Not a blog.

Comment: Don't tag questions with irrelevant languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we look at the matrix:

```
3 4 6
7 7 7
3 4 0
```

As a memory map addressed in the following manner (sequentially):

```
0 1 2 
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

The quoted text is making a perfect sense. There is `7`s in the addresses `3` and `4`, and the next instruction is `3 4 0` located at address `6`.